# how do we change the name format based on language

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my application I have two languages English and Chinese. When I
 choose English, the name format should be first name and last name. But, when I choose Chinese, it should be in the reverse order, that is, last name and first name.How to do that using angular JS?

```
<div ng-if="lan.value == 'APP.LANGUAGE.EN_GB'">
  {{vm.userIdentity.lastname}} {{vm.userIdentity.firstname}}
</div>
<div ng-if="lan.value!== 'APP.LANGUAGE.EN_GB'">
  {{xxx.firstname}} {{xxx.lastname}}
</div>
```

I tried that but that's not working.

Comment: why have you tagged `jquery` when the question is about `angular`?

Comment: Are you sure that `lan.value` is filled properly? To verify, create a label tag with an attribute `ng-bind="APP.LANGUAGE.EN_GB"` to make sure.

Comment: @RajaShekar I've suggested you to use `filters` in my answer.. but you can also use `functions` but I guess `filters` would be a more appropriate way..

Answer (score 0):

A simple Solution could be to make a custom filter like this one and pass in all the things you need.

```
angular.module('appFilters', []).filter('nameformat', function() {
  return function(input,lang) {
    //You can change this to switch cases or something
    return lang == 'APP.LANGUAGE.EN_GB' ? input.lastname + " " + input.firstname: input.firstname + " " + input.lastname ;
  };
});
```

in your app

```
angular.module('myApp', ['appFilters']);
```

and in your div simply

```
<div>
  {{ vm.userIdentity | nameformat:lan.value }} 
</div>
```

working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzf3P/47/)